# Structures definitions colliding

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to implement a binary tree for our group project. First of here is some code.

Binary tree structure:

```
typedef struct tBSTNode 
{
    string *Key;        
    tVariable_Prom *BSTNodeCont;    
    struct tBSTNode * LPtr;         
    struct tBSTNode * RPtr;         
} tBSTNodePtr;
```

The data of the tree (*BSTNodeCont) looks like this:

```
typedef struct Variable_Prom {
    int TYPE;
    double DOUBLE;
    int INTEGER;
    bool BOOL;
    string *StringProm;
} tVariable_Prom;
```

But I also need to store array of pointers to some binary tree Nodes in a few special cases...

So I thinked of adding this line to my data structure:

```
tBSNodePtr *pointer;
```

And then malloc it to the custom array size. But here I encounter a problem, because my first structure needs the second structure to be defined at the time, but also my second structure needs the first structure to be defined first (because it is using it).

Is there some header to structures as to functions? Or is there a simple solution to my problem which I am not seeing?

EDIT: info for the questions below.
I have included a header file in my .c file wich contains another header file in which is this definition that seems to work.

```
struct tVariable_Prom;


typedef struct tBSTNode 
{
    string*Key;                                                               
    struct tVariable_Prom *BSTNodeCont;                                       
    struct tBSTNode * LPtr;                                    
    struct tBSTNode * RPtr;                                  
} tBSTNodePtr;

typedef struct Variable_Prom {
    int Typ;
    double DoUbLe;
    int InTeGer;
    bool BoOl;
    string *StringProm;
    struct tBSTNode *pointer;
} tVariable_Prom;
```

Here is the malloc where foo is of type `tVariable_Prom`:

```
foo.pointer = malloc(2 * sizeof(tBSTNodePtr));
```

And a function which searches the binary tree by the Node key(`Tstr`) and returns address to the Node on success (`odkaz3`):

```
BSTSearch(&odkaz3, *strom, &Tstr);
```

Then I am trying to assign an adress of another Node, it is done by another function but practically the problem is there:

```
odkaz3->BSTNodeCont->pointer[0] = *odkaz2;
```

EDIT2: Ok I started over again reading what you said to me, now I have 2 header files
tVariable_Prom.h:

```
struct tBSTNodePtr;

typedef struct Variable_Prom {
    int Typ;
    double DoUbLe;
    int InTeGer;
    bool BoOl;
    string *StringProm;
    tBSTNodePtr *pointer;
} tVariable_Prom;
```

tBSTNodePtr.h:

```
struct tVariable_Prom;

typedef struct tBSTNode {
    string *Key;                                     
    tVariable_Prom *BSTNodeCont;                             
    struct tBSTNode * LPtr;                                  
    struct tBSTNode * RPtr;                                  
} tBSTNodePtr;
```

I have both header files included in parser.h which is included in parser.c but I do get these errors now:

```
tBSTNodePtr.h:5:2: error: unknown type name tVariable_Prom
```

And on line with`odkaz4->BSTNodeCont->pointer[1] = *odkaz3;`:

```
parser.c request for member 'pointer' in something not a structure or union
```

Comment: The compiler complains about an incomplete type because it isn't finding the type definition, but a forward declaration only. Somehow you're not including the header of the type in question.

Comment: I have edited the code again as you said but I am still encountering errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **forward declarations.**

```
struct tVariable_Prom;

typedef struct tBSTNode 
{
    string *Key;        
    tVariable_Prom *BSTNodeCont;    
    struct tBSTNode * LPtr;         
    struct tBSTNode * RPtr;         
} tBSTNodePtr;
```

and vice-versa. And (optionally) put them in two different headers.

Comment: You need to use `struct tVariable_Prom` in `tBSTNode` since you haven't `typedef`ed it yet. (Also, they don't even have to be in separate headers!)

Comment: Thanks for the advice but now I have got a problem when I am trying to assign pointer to the node I malloced like this `tVariable_Prom temp` `temp.pointer = malloc(2 * sizeof(tBSTNodePtr))` I have got a pointer `addr` which points to the Node where the array is allocated but how do I get to the value of the array? I tryied this: `addr->BSTNodeCont->pointer[0] = addr2;` but i got an error: dereferecing pointer to incomplete type ...

Comment: Anybody have answer to my question above?

Comment: Where is that malloc happening? If it's a function you can put it in a .cpp file (is this C or C++?) in which you include both headers before that function call.

Comment: I dont know what a .cpp file is and I am programming in C. The malloc is called in the same function as the assignment is.

Comment: .cpp files are C++ source files. Don't worry, it's irrelevant. So you have a function in a .c file, right? It needs to have both struct declarations available and the definitions for those structs that you are actually using. So you should have something like `#include "BSTNode.h"` and `#include "VarProm.h"` at the top of your .c file where the function is. In those headers you define the structs like I said in the answer above, i.e. using forward declarations to make them work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about the difference between objects and pointers to objects.  You've confusingly `typedef`'d `tBSTNodePtr` to be the same as `tBSTNode` (an object) rather than as a pointer.  Calling some non-pointer a pointer is sure to lead to confusion.

You say you want to have an array of pointers in your `tVariable_Prom`, but then you define a single pointer and set it to point to an array of objects, not an array of pointers.  What you probabaly want is to add

```
struct tBSTNode **pointers;
```

to your tVariable_Prom, and allocate it with

```
foo.pointers = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct tBSTNode *));   // make an array of 2 pointers
```

Then you can probably do something like

```
odkaz3->BSTNodeCont->pointers[0] = odkaz2;
```

where `odkaz2` and `odkaz3` are point pointers to nodes.

Comment: hmmm I think i am doomed to not do this. I tryed to malloc it the way you typed, but the error of unknown `tBSTNode` pops out. So i added name `struct` to malloc before tBSTNode. But the worst error still persist and that is the: `Dereferencing pointer to incomplete Type` But thanks to all that tryed to help.